# AngularJS ng-repeat with filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use filter to exclude an item from a list using the filter:object method.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 <div ng-init="itemList = [
{ id: 'item1', name: 'item 1' },
{ id: 'item2', name: 'item 2' },
{ id: 'item3', name: 'item 3' } ];test='item2';">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in itemList | filter:{ id: '!{{ test }}' }">{{ item.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ulOQKmJthQhIn5PCKTUS?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need curly brackets inside angular expression. Also since `test` is a variable, not actual value to negate you need to concatenate it with the string `!` to get final filter condition.

It will be:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in itemList | filter:{ id: '!' + test }">{{ item.name }}</li>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/vowrYe3aHLrmwmb1ounK?p=info